# Does ClickHouseDB ReplicatedMergeTree prevents adding same column twice?

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to understand what will happen if my application will attempt to add 2 columns simultaneously to ClickHouseDB table based on `ReplicatedMergeTree` engine using 2 different nodes. Will ClickHouse reject one of the ALTERs or will it fail to apply?

So I have 2 nodes A and B and table `alter_test`. And then I run on node A

```
ALTER TABLE alter_test ADD COLUMN Added1 UInt32 FIRST;
```

and at the same time on node B

```
ALTER TABLE alter_test ADD COLUMN Added1 String FIRST;
```

Will I always have 1 of the statements failed? I tried the docs and they say that the ALTERs are executed asynchronously after registering in Zookeeper. I guess my question is if ClickHouse will detect the conflict on the Zookeeper stage.

Comment: With some luck you will get a broken table, even if you use exactly the same column.

Answer (score -1):

Better use

```sql
ALTER TABLE alter_test ON CLUSTER 'cluster_name' ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS Added1 Uint32
```

Comment: That will not fail and my app will not know that the column already added of a wrong type.